# Print awk output into new column

Tags: bash, loops, awk

I have lot of files modified (after filtration) and I need to print NR and characters about new files into column - lets see example:

```
input files: x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3 ...
```

script:

```
for i in x* y* z*

 do awk -v h=$i 'END{c+=lenght+1 ;print h "\t" NR "\t" c}' >> stats.txt

done;
```

my output looks like:

```
x1 NR c
x2 NR c
x3 NR c
y1 NR c
y2 NR c
y3 NR c
z1 NR c
z2 NR c
z3 NR c
```

And I need to save each loop to new column no line:

```
x1 NR c y1 NR c z1 NR c

x2 NR c y2 NR c z2 NR c

x3 NR c y3 NR c z3 NR c
```

to keep corresponding files (after filtration) on the same line. I hope I am clear. I need to do this in BASH and awk. Thank you for any help!!

EDITED:

the real output look like:

```
    x   0.457143    872484
    y   0.527778    445759
    z   0.416667    382712
    x   0.457143    502528
    y   0.5         575972
    z   0.444444    590294
    x   0.371429    463939
    y   0.694444    398033
    z   0.56565     656565
    .
    .
    .
```

and I need:

```
x 0.457143  872484 0.457143 502528 0.371429 463939
y 0.52777   445759 0.5      575972 0.694444 398033
.
.
.
```

I hope it is clear..

Comment: it is a bit unclear what you mean. Literal `NR` and `c` or they contain some values?

Comment: @fedorqui I am sorry, yeas NR is numebr of rows in document and C is word count - afters some filtrations it is changing.

Comment: no problem! Note that `for i in x* y* z*` will expand all `x*`, `y*` and `z*` to a big list and every loop will pick one of the items. So in fact there is not such a thing of a loop containing one item from `x*`, another from `y*` and another from `z*`.

Comment: Post some sample input and the output you expect from that input so we can help you. How are x, y, etc in your output related to x1, x2, etc? How are all those numbers less than 1 related to you wanting to print the number of lines and number of characters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
cat data | tr -d , | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 3) print $i " NR c " $(i+1) " NR c " $(i+2) " NR c"}'
```

Output:

```
x1 NR c x2 NR c x3 NR c
y1 NR c y2 NR c y3 NR c
z1 NR c z2 NR c z3 NR c
```

Same table but transposed (for your task variant):

```bash
cat data | tr -d , | awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF/3; i += 1) print $i " NR c " $(i+3) " NR c " $(i+6) " NR c"}'
```

Output:

```
x1 NR c y1 NR c z1 NR c
x2 NR c y2 NR c z2 NR c
x3 NR c y3 NR c z3 NR c
```

**For your task update** check the following solution (using *bash*):

```bash
cat data | sort | while read L;
do
  y=`echo $L | cut -f1 -d' '`;
  {
    test "$x" = "$y" && echo -n " `echo $L | cut -f2- -d' '`";
  } ||
  {
    x="$y";echo -en "\n$L";
  };
done
```

(from my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897255/how-to-merge-similar-lines-in-linux/18018828#18018828) for similar problem)

**Updated script after comment:**

```bash
sort data | while read L 
do
  y="`echo \"$L\" | cut -f1 -d' '`"
  if [ "$x" = "$y" ]
  then
    echo -n " `echo \"$L\" | cut -f2- -d' '`"
  else
    x="$y"
    echo -en "\n$L"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @ rook Thank you so much for your time. Do you think it is possible to modife if my output have the same name x y and z (without index x1, x2, x3 ...)? TThank you for help.

Comment: yes, this should work, also if you want to output `NR` awk variable, then you could write `print` line without quoted spaces: `print $i, NR, ...` or `print $i NR` without comma - this will output `$i` and `NR` without space between them

Comment: This is wrong in SO many ways. UUOC, incorrect use of read, missing IFS setting, useless pipes, deprecated use of backticks, unnecessary shell loop, useless trailing semi-colons, unquoted variables, etc. etc.

Comment: Semi-colons were used to easy make this script transformed in one line. I also intentionally didn't use `if`, `then` construct to reduce the number of the symbols on the screen. Agree, that `cat` is excessive. So.. copypast of previous work :)